# Deleting Objects with Django Delete

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-models

I have an issue deleting just a single object from my database, I have a code that gets a list of RDS hostnames from AWS and then compares the rds hostnames stored in my Database to that returned by AWS, if the rds hostname is stored in  my DB and not returned by AWS it should be removed from my database, but my code eventually ends up removing all the RDS hostnames stored in my DB

Here is my models

```
class AwsAssets(BaseModel):
    aws_access_token = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    aws_secret_token = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    rds_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(
        self.client_aws_access_token,
        self.client_aws_secret_token
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Aws Assets"


class AwsRdsNames(BaseModel):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    port = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    asset_link = models.ForeignKey(AwsAssets, null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="rds_endpoints", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    region = models.CharField(max_length=56, null=True, blank=True)
    scan_status = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)
    last_scan = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}:{}".format(self.host, self.port)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'aws_rds_names'
        ordering = ['-id']
```

and then here is the block of code responsible for deleting the rds hostnames

```
all_stored_rds = AwsRdsNames.objects.all()
stored_rds = all_stored_rds.filter(asset_link=self.asset) #This returns all the stored rds hosts  in db
aws_rds = get_rds() #This returns a list of rds hostname from aws

for rds in stored_rds:
     if rds.host not in aws_rds:
          AwsRdsNames.objects.filter(host=rds.host).delete()
```

this code ends up deleting all the rds hosts stored in my DB instead of removing the ones not returned by aws

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a list with the names from of the existing domains:

```
domains = ["domain1", "domain2", "domain3", ...]
for entry in AwsRdsNames.objects.all():
   if entry.host not in domains:
       entry.delete()
```

That should do.

Comment: Thank you, I think this would do the opposite, which is to delete all the domains returned by aws

Comment: Not really.  It is removing the entries that are not in the list

Comment: still ends up deleting everything, I am suspecting the foreign key relation but i cant wrap my head around why it keeps removing everything

Comment: You will probably need to update the on_delete behavior, from cascade to set_null

Answer (score 0):

To delete it directly:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

To delete it from instance:

```
instance = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
instance.delete()
```